# How to list files on terminal so that we can see the file types such executable, ascii etc?

Tags: command-line, files, ls, file-command

I have been trying to list files in directory using ls and passing it different options.

Does it have the ability to list types of files as well ? I want to know which ones are executable , sharedlibs or just ascii files without doing file command on individual files.

Comment: old timers uses `file`, nowaday you can also use `mimetype`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` itself won't show this information.

You can pipe the output of the `find` to `file -f -`, as follows:

```
$ find /usr/local/bin | file -f -
/usr/local/bin:              directory 
/usr/local/bin/apt:                  Python script, ASCII text executable
/usr/local/bin/mint-md5sum:                          ASCII text
/usr/local/bin/search:                     Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/usr/local/bin/gnome-help:                         Python script, ASCII text executable
/usr/local/bin/office-vb.sh:                           ASCII text
/usr/local/bin/pastebin:                       Python script, ASCII text executable
/usr/local/bin/highlight:                        POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
/usr/local/bin/yelp:                   Python script, ASCII text executable
```

Note that `find` is used instead of `ls` as it will print the full path, whereas `ls` will only print the file name.  Therefore, if you simply need to do this with the files in your current directory, then:

```
ls | file -f -
```

would work.

Comment: i assume you meant to run `file` on the `ls` output in the last example

Comment: You can use `file *`, `file /usr/local/bin/*`, etc. Piping from find is useful though if you have too many files for globbing, or want to use find's other features such as listing only recently modified files.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` doesn't do this. Its job is to report on file metadata (permissions, timestamp, etc.), not on file contents. But `file` itself does (combined with a shell wildcard to list all files):

```
file *
```

for the current directory, or

```
file /some/directory/*
```

in another directory.

If you want to combine metadata and file content information, you can combine the output of `ls` and `file`. One way is to arrange for two commands to list one file per line in the same order, and use the [`paste`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) utility to combine them — something like

```
paste <(ls -dlog -- *) <(file -b -- *)
```

(This uses process substitution, which is available in common interactive shells: bash, zsh, also in ksh93.) If you have the [`column`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) utility, it's a convenient way of aligning the columns:

```
paste <(ls -dlog -- *) <(file -b -- *) | column -ts $'\t'
```

If you want to output the fields in a different order, [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) the fields on the file name instead. I do a bit of back-and-forth between spaces and tabs to cope with file names containing spaces and produce vertically aligned results.

```
join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 <(ls -dlog -- * |
                          sed 's/^\([^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*\)  */\1\t/') \
                        <(file -- * | sed 's/: */\t/') |
column -ts $'\t'
```